# The function $f : R → R$ satisfies $x + f(x) = f(f(x))$ for every $x\in R$. Find all solutions of the equation $f(f(x)) = 0$.

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> The function $f : R → R$ satisfies $x + f(x) = f(f(x))$ for every $x\in R$. Find all solutions of the equation $f(f(x)) = 0$.

I found its answer online [here](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0). The solution given is:

> The domain of this function is $R$, so there isn't much hope that this can be solved using mathematical induction. Notice that $f(f(x))-f(x)=x$ and if $f(x)=f(y)$ then clearly $x=y$. This means that the function is injective. Since $f(f(0))=f(0)+0=f(0)$, because of injectivity we must have $f(0)=0$, implying $f(f(0))=0$. If there were another $x$ such that $f(f(x))=x$, injectivity would imply $f(x)=f(0)$ and $x=0$

I understood most of it except how they implied injectivity. I understand if $f(x)=f(y)$ is giving $x=y$ it implies injectivity. But how is it implied from $f(f(x))-f(x)=x$?

If I put $f(x)=y$, I get $f(y)-y=x\implies f(y)=y+x$ i.e. $f(y)=f(x)+x$. Not getting $f(y)=f(x)$.

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: @Bernard Real numbers. Is this not implied?

Comment: Hi, if $f(x) = f(y)$,then $x = f(f(x))-f(x) = f(f(y))-f(y) = y$.

Comment: $f(x)=f(y)$ then $f(f(x))=f(f(y))$, subtracting these two equations gives $x=y$.

Comment: The standard notations are $\Bbb R$ or $\mathbf R$. Usually $R$ denotes a ring (for english language users).

Comment: @LukasBetz got it, thanks.

Comment: @N.Quy got it, thanks.

Comment: @Bernard thanks. I'll take care next time.

Comment: @Saad that answers my question. Thanks. And sorry for the duplicacy. I had searched it online. I didn't find any MSE links.